# JavaFX - What is the purpose of JavaFX-Fallback-Class?

Tags: java, javafx

I have found an entry in `MANIFEST.MF` file of some JavaFX project:

```
JavaFX-Fallback-Class:
```

But I cannot find out what is it used for, search on Google did not give any reasonable result. So my question is:

> What is the purpose of fallback class in JavaFX?
>   When does is it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it used to create some sort of backup solution when your application is lacking required version of JavaFX, JRE or whatever.

As an example of fallback class you can refer to this link:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/javafx/main/NoJavaFXFallback.java